# Send Email Again in device system in rails

Tags: devise

I have a question about the area to send again the email to confirm the account.

The previous developer of the website added this

```
<%- if devise_mapping.confirmable? && controller_name != 'confirmations' %>
    <%= link_to 'Send Email Again', new_confirmation_path(resource_name) %>
<% end -%>
```

Why?
I am new on rails, but I don't undestand why he added this if condition.

Also because I noted that I can see this link both logged both not logged.

Comment: This video will  help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INPqBOerfTw&t=1s

Comment: @nourza ... where?